# DynamoDB scan seems to not do anything

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Basically, trying to scan a DynamoDB table to correct a data problem (which is why it is a scan):

```
var tableName = dynamoDbMapperProvider.getTableName(DynamoSnapshot.class, address);
log("Starting re-encryption for table " + tableName);
int migratedSnapshotsCount = 0;
for (var snapshot : dynamoDBMapper.scan(DynamoSnapshot.class, snapshotScanExpression)) {
    if (snapshot.getEncryptedKey() != null) {
        try {
            encryptionService.decrypt(
                EnvelopeMessage.of(snapshot.getBinaryData(), snapshot.getEncryptedKey(), snapshot.getCmkId())
            );
            // decryption okay so just set Cmk to configured value as a side-effect...
            log("Updating CmkId for " + snapshot.getRootId());
            dynamoDBMapper.save(snapshot.withCmkId(cmkId));
        } catch (EncryptDecryptException ex) {
            if (ex.isKmsError()) {
                // ... reencrypt and log...
                migratedSnapshotsCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
log(
    "Re-encrypt encrypted key process completed for table " + tableName + ", " + migratedSnapshotsCount +
        " Snapshots migrated and re-encrypted."
);
```

This is running in the cloud so I cannot debug this locally. I would expect at least 2 log messages, but we're only getting the 1st from before the for-each loop and then nothing, no exceptions, just nothing. How is that even possible?

Comment: Q: Why can't you run your Java code locally (e.g. in Eclipse), so you can set breakpoints and step through the code?  You need to troubleshoot exactly WHERE your code is failing to "return something".  Running in a debugger is arguably the fastest way to accomplish this.  Just because the DB is in the cloud ... shouldn't mean you can't debug Java locally.

Comment: Because the DB is in the cloud, it isn't accessible locally (security, ya know). I can see it through the AWS Console, but the whole setup to enable that isn't available to me locally.

Comment: You should be able to connect like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html.  Alternatively, you should be able to use Cloud9: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-java.html.  As a last resort, you can put judicious "println()" or "log()" statements in your code.  But you MUST be able to trace the code path, in order to determine where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Scan is lazily loaded by default. Try setting the scan to EAGER_LOADING so that the data is returned on execution.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.PaginationLoadingStrategy.html

Comment: Doesn't work any differently.